# Excel web part not refreshing - Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, excel, 2016, refresh

There is problem with refreshing of Excel web access web part on Sharepoint online.

I have made lists on Sharepoint end exported them in excel (got .jqy file), made pivot table, edited workbook and I want to show it as excel web part. 
In excel I also set refresh options in Data->Connections and I tried to connect data form OData Feed. It can be done two ways, I tried both.

First one: Data -> New Query -> From Other Sources -> From OData Feed -> URL to SharePoint .

it showed error:

> "The user was not authorized";

and second: Data -> From Other Sources -> From OData Feed -> Link or File on Sharepoint.

it showed error:

> "we couldn't connect to the data source. Please check your log on
>   information. Here's the error message we got: The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

I tried this several times, on demo tenant and on production, and with different sets of data. Also, my credentials should be fine  - I don't have a problem anywhere else and I don't have restrictions to any of the sites I worked on.

I want that my excel web part (pivot table) has updated information which come from SharePoint list. Why is this function not working?